# how to disable launcher icon in android from the list when all the app shown in the list?

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an app in this all the application shown in list view which are already installed in device. I want to disable the the app using Toggle Button. But when ever I am trying to do this it's only disable the my app .

```
                    PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
                    p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(),
                    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

But it not taken from the list . It's only disable my app not others .

Please Help me ...
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because your app doesn't have permission to do that.

Check in this direction, now I don't know if you can do it by make your app As device administrator app (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html), but more probably you need root permission to do it

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file use

```
<activity>
 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />// default to hide the image from the launcher
</activity>
```